# Why can't I enable hyper-v on windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8, hyper-v

I'm running windows 8 64 bit, 4gb ram, on an i5 3230. According to the specs, my hardware meets the requirements to enable it, but It's not listed on enable windows features. I downloaded coreinfo tool that confirms my hardware is compatible: I'm trying to write a windows phone 8 app and I wasn't able to run the emulator due to hyper-v not being installed. Anyone have any info?

```
Coreinfo v3.2 - Dump information on system CPU and memory topology
Copyright (C) 2008-2012 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
HYPERVISOR      -       Hypervisor is present
VMX             *       Supports Intel hardware-assisted virtualization
EPT             *       Supports Intel extended page tables (SLAT)
```

Comment: You need Windows 8 Pro.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I guess I could partition Hyper-V Server 2012 R2 on my machine and should be able to install visual studio 2012. Thanks for the insight. No thanks to microsoft for making this a pain in the ass!

Answer (score 0):

What version of Windows 8 do you have? You need Windows 8 Pro 64bits or greater to be able to enable HyperV.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to enable CPU virtualization from the BIOS